# How to know accessibility software is ON in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, mobile-browser, section508

I would like to display/program my HTML page differently with and without accessibility feature is ON.

How to know accessibility software ( talkback in android , voicevoer in iOS) is ON in mobile browser ?

Is there any JavaScript variable available/object to know the above?

**Observation**

In Android Chrome browser,  if accessibility is on, software is inserting couple of JavaScript files into browser. for example, chromeVoxChromePageScript.js, etc.
chromeVoxChromePageScript.js file has a cvox object.

we can keep if accessibility is on:

```
if(typeof cvox !== "undefined" ){
 // specific code
}
```

is there any better way in iOS/android?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a method in iOS. One of the main principles of [Apple's iOS accessibility approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html) is:

> Making standard UIKit controls and views accessible by default.

I.e. allowing developers to make what they create accessible, rather than needing a separate interface. Accessibility should be part of the mainstream.

Could you share the feature that you think needs to be separate?

The feature you found in Android is interesting, but does that work in Firefox? (FF is generally more reliable to use with Talkback.)

Comment: I am developing a framework, where I have to handle many cases. So I need to make some design changes with or without Accessibility feature

I am still doing R&D on this for various OS. I will share the results.